# ^[A-Za-Z ][A-Za-z0-9 ]* regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

The regular expression `^[A-Za-Z ][A-Za-z0-9 ]*` describe "first letter should be alphabet and remaining letter may be alpha numerical". But how do I also allow special characters?  When I enter "C#" it is raising an error.

How do I enter a special character and first letter should alphabet?

Comment: This should also be tagged regexp

Comment: @joemoe: I tagged it "regex" for you.

Comment: note that as typed, it is "the first character should be alpha *or space*..."

Answer (score 19):

A lot of the answers given so far are pretty good, but you must clearly define what it is exactly that you want.

If you would like a alphabetical character followed by any number of non-white-space characters (note that it would also include numbers!) then you should use this:

```
^[A-Za-z]\S*$
```

If you would like to include only alpha-numeric characters and certain symbols, then use this:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*]*$
```

Your original question looks like you are trying to include the space character as well, so you probably want something like this:

```
^[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]*$
```

And that is my final answer!

I suggest taking some time to learn more about regular expressions. They are the greatest thing since sliced bread!

Try this [syntax reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) page (that site in general is very good).

Comment: @Peter Di Cecco: You forgot 0-9.

Answer (score 4):

This expression will force the first letter to be alphabetic and the remaining characters to be alphanumeric or any of the following special characters: @,#,%,&,*

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@#%&*]*$
```

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: Ok, I modified the regex to include @,%,&,* too.

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: Do you want to allow spaces? Your original regex in the title appears to allow spaces.

Comment: @Xinus: No. * doesn't need to be escaped when it's within a character class.

Comment: How to add Space in that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

^[A-Za-z ].*

Comment: It is not taking as expression Mr. Joemoe

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
^[A-Za-z]\S*
```

a letter followed by 0 or more non-space characters (will include all special symbols).

Answer (score 1):

This expression will check if the first letter to be alphabetic and the remaining characters to be alphanumeric or any of the following special characters: `@,#,%,&,`

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@#%&\*]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

First must be Alphabet and then dot not allowed in target string.
below is code.

```
        string input = "A_aaA";

        // B
        // The regular expression we use to match
        Regex r1 = new Regex("^[A-Za-z][^.]*$"); //[\t\0x0020] tab and spaces.

        // C
        // Match the input and write results
        Match match = r1.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid: {0}", match.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Match");
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

this expression is to get only numbers

```
    If Regex.IsMatch(mystring, "^[A-Za-z ].*|\s") Then
        MessageBox.Show("please fill the box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
       
    ElseIf (mystring = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("please fill the box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
      
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an email validation

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
^[A-Za-z](\W|\w)*
```

`(\W|\w)` will ensure that every subsequent letter is word(`\w`) or non word(`\W`)

instead of `(\W|\w)*` you can also use `.*` where `.` means absolutely anything just like `(\w|\W)`

Comment: How is this different from "^[A-Za-z].*" or even "^[A-Za-z]"?

Comment: @Xinus: the character class [\W|\w] means word characters, the | character, or non-word characters. If you changed your square braces to parenthesis, it would mean what you claimed. But it could still be more simply and more elegantly expressed.

Comment: @Asaph: I do not have much experience with regular expressions ... I think you are saying sounds logical, I am changing it to parenthesis ...

Comment: @paxdiablo: "^[A-Za-z]" would only match the first character, not the whole word. "^[A-Za-z].*" will work fine though, as Xinus also stated after his edit.

Comment: @Xinus This answer is likely not correct. The initial regular expression matches a valid C identifier. This solution will, unfortunately match "FOO\n\n\n" as well as "C#".

Comment: `(\W|\w)` is *not* the same as `.` since `\W` will always include newlines, whilst for `.` it depends on the mode.

Comment: @Marc, if you're using the start anchor (^), I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that a missing end anchor ($) means just match at the start of the string. That's why I asked what the difference was. If it matches the whole string, then the start anchor would be superfluous.